# Looking to split a scatterplot and return the highest values (images included)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have two columns in R called A and B where I created a scatter plot for. (Both scatter plots are identical one just has the labels added to them).

I want to identify the names of the items after the cut off line. There are about 11 points above the cut off line, how can I go about doing this in R?

Create a data table of all values greater than 1e+05? Just looking for some direction, thanks.

Plot 1:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
  geom_point(fill = "red")
```

Plot 2:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
  geom_point(fill = "red") +
geom_text(label=rownames(df))
```

Sample of A:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dvFB.jpg) 1136   12  203  147    9    3   12   83   82 1304

Sample of B:
1852   90  277  329   15    8   30  165  156 2572

[Two Identical Scatterplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dvFB.jpg)

Comment: Take a look at the `identify` function

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel) # will avoid overlapping of values above the cut off

A <- c( 1136, 12, 203, 147, 9, 3, 12, 83, 82, 1304)
B <- c(1852, 90, 277, 329, 15, 8, 30, 165, 156, 2572)
df <- data.frame(A , B)
df$id <- ifelse(df$A > 1e+03 & df$B > 1e+03, B, NA) # just an example of cut off.

ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_text_repel(aes(x = A, y = B, label = id), size = 2.5, na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]